# Python Recursively check for repeats

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have an assignment I've been stuck on for a couple days now. I have to recursively figure out if a list has repeats but I cannot use any loops or built in functions besides len(). I'm also not allowed to use the 'in' function. Returns True if list L has repeats, False otherwise. This is what I've been able to figure out:

```
def has_repeats(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return False
    elif L[0] == L[1]:
        return True
    else: return has_repeats(L[0] + L[2:])
```

But the problem with that is it's only comparing the first element to the rest, instead of each element to the rest. I can't figure out how to do that without a running counter or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you allowed to send the counter in as a param to your method, and then do an increment for each time you check an item?

Comment: No, it has to be 1 parameter has_repeats(L)

Comment: With only one recursive call within the function, you'll only be able to check one element at a time.  Hint: try checking both of the first two elements to see if they are contained in the rest of the list.

Comment: Can you have multiple parameters with default values so the top-level call is `has_repeats(L)`, but sub-calls can leverage additional params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it. Along with checking the first element with the rest of the list, you also need to check the *second* the same way:

```
def has_repeats(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return False
    if L[0] == L[1]:
        return True
    if has_repeats([L[0]] + L[2:]):
        return True
    if has_repeats(L[1:]):
        return True
    return False
```

You can also compact this into the following representation:

```
def has_repeats(L):
    return len(L)>1 and L[0]==L[1] or has_repeats([L[0]]+L[2:]) or has_repeats(L[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper function:

```
 def helper(ele, rest):
    if not rest:
        return False
    return ele == rest[0] or helper(ele, l[1:])

def has_repeats(l):
    if not l:
        return False
    return helper(l[0], l[1:]) or has_repeats(l[1:])
```